# RRule - rrule.all() returns dates array with wrong dates

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, rrule

I am using `RRULE` in javascript to create recurring events. This is the code I am using for creating an `RRule`

```
const rule = new RRule({
  freq: RRule.MONTHLY,
  dtstart: new Date("2023-1-1"),
  until: null,
  count: 2,
  byMonthDay: 19,
});

const dates = rule.all()

// OUTPUT 
Fri Jan 20 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time) 
Mon Feb 20 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
```

You see `rule.all()` returns 20th of each date. Ideally, it should return 19th of each month.

When I set `dtstart = null`, things work alright. Another thing I did was to set dtstart like below

```
const startDate = new Date("2023-1-1")
dtstart = new Date(Date.UTC(startDate.getFullYear(),startDate.getMonth(),startDate.getDate(),0,0,0)
```

This made things work for me but after this change, my colleague (location: San Francisco) started facing this issue. In my case, I was getting dates one day in the future. He started getting dates one day in the past

I think it has something to do with timezones. He lives in `GMT -8` and I am in `UTC +5`

The issue I see is with `dtstart` value. I can't figure out the date that I need to pass to it to make it work with all timezones.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

startDate.getDate() - you're getting the local time here (the current time of your node.js/browser environment).
You can use libraries (e.g. dayjs) to set default timezone.